# XML Mutator Error when executing Stored Proc via BCP in SQL Job

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a Stored Proc that grabs some data as XML. I configured a SQL Job to trigger the cmd shell bcp utility to output to xml file. When I run the sql job, I am getting the error below:

```
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 5302  Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Mutator 'modify()' on '@XMLData' cannot be called on a null value.  Process Exit Code 1.  The step failed.
```

This is the line in the SP that is causing the above error.

```
SET @XMLData.modify('insert <NoOfItems>{ xs:string(sql:variable("@NoOfItems")) }</NoOfItems> as first into (/Item)[1]')
```

However, I am very sure it is not null. I even check if it is null before triggering the modify call. Also if I run the stored proc directly in SSMS, it runs fine. There is something in bcp I don't understand why it will cause this.

Below is the Stored Proc:

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML
DECLARE @NoOfItems int

SET @NoOfItems = (Select COUNT(*) from ItemInfo)

If (@NoOfItems > 0)
BEGIN
SET @XMLData = 
(
Select      
   ItemNo,
    (    
        select     
        Name,    
        Contents    
        from  ItemInfo rsItemContent   
        where rsItemContent.ItemNo = rsItems.ItemNo    
        for xml path('Content'), type    
    )
from (select distinct ItemNo from IELSBE_V12.dbo.GDInfo) rsItems join ItemInfo II on rsItems.ItemNo = II.ItemNo
FOR XML PATH ('ItemInfo'), root ('Item')
)
if @XMLData is not null
BEGIN
SET @XMLData.modify('insert <NoOfItems>{ xs:string(sql:variable("@NoOfItems")) }</NoOfItems> as first into (/Item)[1]')
select @XMLData
END
END
```

Comment: Include in your question a minimal data set that showcases the problem.

Comment: Your `@NoOfItems` will be the total count for the whole table ItemInfo. I think this is not what you want. The check for `>0` should be true in any case... Second: Your `select distinct` pulls data from a different server? Could you please explain the structure against you run this query?